# External List Error : The query against the database caused an error

Tags: list, iis, bcs

I got an SQL Server 2008 R2 and a SharePoint Server. I have put up a BCS between the two servers. Reading data through a External List. This worked fine yesterday. But to day I got this error:

The query against the database caused an error.

```
Correlation ID:7ebc312e-db3a-46a4-afbe-04b0115c4885

w3wp.exe (0x0CB4)-0x1AD8-SharePoint Foundation-Logging Correlation Data-xmnv-Medium Name=Request (POST:http://External%20List/Read%20List.aspx)-7ebc312e-db3a-46a4fbe-04b0115c4885
```

Some of the guys I work with have reset the IIS, can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of searching and debugging I finally found out what the problem was:

**Somebody had removed read/write access from the user I created in SQL Server. When checking Read/Write boxes everything works fine again.**

If you want to learn about  BCS: Take a look at this video about [Business Connectivity Services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/video-business-connectivity-services-authentication-from-the-browser-VA101873629.aspx)